# Iterate over certificates in windows powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

Powershell provides access to the certificates on a windows 7 machine in the following way:

```
  PS C:\Users\z0017fjy> cd cert:
PS cert:\> dir


Location   : CurrentUser
StoreNames : {SmartCardRoot, UserDS, AuthRoot, CA...}

Location   : LocalMachine
StoreNames : {SmartCardRoot, AuthRoot, CA, Trust...}



PS cert:\> cd .\LocalMachine
PS cert:\LocalMachine> dir


Name : SmartCardRoot

Name : AuthRoot

Name : CA

Name : Trust

Name : Disallowed

Name : SMS

Name : My

Name : Root

Name : TrustedPeople

Name : TrustedDevices

Name : Remote Desktop

Name : TrustedPublisher

Name : REQUEST
```

Now I want to iterate over the cert folder using the following pseudocode:

```
for each subfolder in cert:
  for each certstore in subfolder:
     for each cert in certstore:
        print cert.information
```

How would I do that in powershell?

Comment: Have you tried `Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\ ` ?

Comment: I have tried it now. Looks good! Please post it as a proper answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificate repository is covered by a `PSProvider` that lets you treat it somewhat like a file system. There are providers also for the registry, wsman settings, and others.

For your purpose:
`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path Cert:\`

You can see other available providers with `Get-PSProvider`.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176857.aspx